# Does Profit and loss has break down on previous/current tax year or full calendar year?

Tags: united-kingdom, accounting, limited-liability-company, services

I'm doing my personal tax return at tax.service.gov.uk for my Limited company and it may be sound very simple question, but it's confusing for me.

Given the following Profit and loss table for tax year 2014/2015:

[image: Profit and loss]

And assuming my tax year is from 2014.05.01-2015.04.31, does the above table is the breakdown:

- per whole calendar year (2014.01.01-2014.12.31 & 2015.01.01-2015.12.31),
- per calendar year within the current tax year (2014.05.01-2014.12.31 & 2015.01.01-2015.04.31),
- or basically 2014 means the previous tax period (2013.05.01-2014.04.31), and 2015 means the current tax period (2014.05.01-2015.04.31)

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have never filed your company's returns before.

Tax year for your company isn't related to calendar year or the financial year(they might be the same, but depends). Your company's financial year is defined when you file your company's Annual return, not accounts. When you file your Annual Return it should have shown you what is the financial year for your company and also gives you the option if you want to change it.

Normally the financial year, for a company, is the 365 days from the date of formation of your company on a rolling basis.

And regarding the P&L table, 2015 signifies the financial year ending for your company and likewise for 2014.